# Generate datasets with c# code within SSRS Report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, datasource

Since it is possible to include c# code within SSRS (.rdl) reports, i was wondering if it is possible to generate datasets from the code within a report.

The motivation behind that question is that i have a datasource on which my reports depend, but i need to perform several calculations for each report before actually showing the result (currently an external application is handling this and writing the result to its own table, which in turn i use as dataset in the report). Obviously including the logic into the report could be done by including code in every single field of my report (which is not an applicable solution since this would be really hard to maintain).
Since the external application is written in c# already, i would rather like to include this code into my .rdl file and use the output as a dataset right away, instead of writing it to the database first.

Is this possible at all (this implies i would need to run code before the report is being built, but i don't know how this can be accomplished)? If this is possible, can i include a whole project or selfbuilt classes in a SSRS report that i can reference from everywhere within the report?

Comment: Are you sure you want to generate a datasource?   Do you maybe mean dataset?

Comment: I will need multiple datasets, but yes that will do. I will edit the questing accordingly, thanks.